# Trying to reference a formula in another sheet using the Index-Match method in Excel (Office 2016)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to reference a formula in another sheet using the Index-Match method. I am referencing this formula every time a certain Feature appears in my main list. For instance, if the Castle Feature appears, the Description column index-matches from a Feature list on another sheet.

The referenced formula is meant to randomize the Creature that owns the Castle. My problem is that because all of my Castles are referencing the same formula, they all end up owned by the same Creature.

There are 700 rows being calculated and 110 different features. Just copying the formula for each one isn't an option. It needs to be dynamic based on the feature on that particular row.

All Descriptions are pulled from the same place: Features! via

```
=index(featuredetails,match(i2,featurelist,0),10)
```

Description Formula on Features sheet:

```
="It's a "&index(creatures,randbetween(1,counta(creatures)),1)&" Castle"
```

**Sheet 1 (the way it is)**

```
 1. | Feature | Description | 
 2. | Castle | It's a Goblin Castle | 
 3. | Castle | It's a Goblin Castle |
```

**Sheet 1 (the way I want it)**

```
 1. | Feature | Description | 
 2. | Castle | It's a Goblin Castle | 
 3. | Castle | It's a **KOBOLD** Castle |
```

Hopefully that's enough explanation.

**I would prefer a formula solution. I'm trying to keep my project office 365 friendly.**

Comment: I have found a solution. I'm using the Evaluate() function in a defined name. It requires saving as a macro workbook, but because I only need to randomize my content, it will work. Once I'm happy with the results, I will stop the randomizing by copy/pasting the values on top of the formulas.This solution required me to FormulaText() the original data in a separate column, then use Evaluate() in a Defined Name to reference the formula text. This was my final Evaluate formula: ```=EVALUATE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(MasterFeature,MATCH(Hexes!$J118,FeatureDescArray,0),12)),17,4,1,"Features")))```

Comment: I'm learning new things here.. thanks for the sharing.. ( :